# import next() python 2.5

Tags: python, iterator, python-2.x

I'm using a slightly altered version of the pairwise recipe from itertools which looks like this

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

Now it turns out I need to run the code with **python 2.5** where the next() function throws  the following exception:

`<type 'exceptions.NameError'>: global name 'next' is not defined`

Is there a way to use next() with python 2.5? Or how do I need to modify the function to make it work anyhow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can easily provide a definition of this function yourself:

```
_sentinel = object()
def next(it, default=_sentinel):
    try:
        return it.next()
    except StopIteration:
        if default is _sentinel:
            raise
        return default
```