# Making 4 lists into a 2 element nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have four lists of varying length.  Also every time I run the program the lengths of each list will be different.

Here is a simple example of 4 possible lists

```
A_list = [1, 2, 3]
B_list = [4]
C_list = [5, 6, 7, 8]
D_list = [9, 10]
```

I would like to make a new list that looks like this:

```
answer = [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [7, 9], [8, 10]]
```

So far this is my code.

```
answer = []
answer.append(list(zip(A_list, B_list)))

if len(A_list) < len(B_list):
        leftover_V_list = V_list[len(B_list):] 
        answer.append(list(zip(leftover_B_list, C_list)))

elif len(A_list) > len(B_list):
        leftover_A_list = A_list[len(B_list):]
        answer.append(list(zip(leftover_A_list, C_list)))

print(answer)

>>> 
[[(1, 4)], [(2, 5), (3, 6)]]
```

So there are some problems with my code.  Here are some things I'm struggling with:

1. I'm getting the correct numbers but they are in the wrong format.
2. I'm unsure how to proceed to the the rest of C_list and D_list
3. How do I deal with the possibility of an empty list

Also I'm pretty sure I'm going about this completely wrong.  There must be a better way to do this.  Please help.
I'm using python 3.2.3

Here are some examples of what the lists can be:

```
A_list = [1]
B_list = [2, 3]
C_list = [4, 5, 6, 7]
D_list = [8]

answer =  [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 8], [6], [7]]

A_list = [1, 2, 3]
B_list = []
C_list = [4]
D_list = [5, 6]

answer =  [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]

A_list = [1, 2, 3]
B_list = []
C_list = []
D_list = [5, 6]

answer =  [[1,5], [2,6], [3]]

A_list = [1]
B_list = [2]
C_list = [3]
D_list = [4]

answer =  [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: I'm curious about the usage of this function.  What's it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phew. I think I got it.  This could be cleaned up a bit I'm sure, but it works for all mentioned cases.  It will also work for any number of lists, and handles empty lists as well.

```
def remove_empties(list1):
    """removes any empty lists from our list"""
    list2 = [x for x in list1 if x]
    return list2

def merge_to_couples(new_list):
    answer = []
    new_list = remove_empties(new_list)

    while True:
        answer.append([new_list[0][0], new_list[1][0]])
        del new_list[0][0], new_list[1][0]

        new_list = remove_empties(new_list) #remove empty lists every iteration

        if len(new_list) == 0: #if length is 0, our work is done
            return answer 
        if len(new_list) == 1: #if length is 1, we need to append remaining numbers as lists with length 1
            for i in new_list[0]:
                answer.append([i])
            return answer


A_list = [1,2,3]
B_list = [4]
C_list = [5,6,7,8]
D_list = [9,10]

new_list = [A_list, B_list, C_list, D_list]

print merge_to_couples(new_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use iterators, and chaining:

```
from itertools import chain

A_iter, B_iter, C_iter, D_iter = (iter(l) for l in (A_list, B_list, C_list, D_list))
chain_a = chain(A_list, B_list)
chain_b = chain(B_list, C_list)

paired = [list(t) for t in chain(zip(chain_a, chain_b), zip(C_iter, D_iter))]
```

Output:

```
>>> A_iter, B_iter, C_iter, D_iter = (iter(l) for l in (A_list, B_list, C_list, D_list))
>>> chain_a = chain(A_iter, B_iter)
>>> chain_b = chain(B_iter, C_iter)
 >>> [list(t) for t in chain(zip(chain_a, chain_b), zip(C_iter, D_iter))]
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [7, 9], [8, 10]]
```

This works with empty lists too, since `chain` will simply skip over those.

Comment: thank you Martijn.  This mostly works. The resulting list is: [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)].  But I need the last two parts to be [7,9] and [8,10].

Comment: Hello Martijn.  I works beautifully except  I need my list to look like this. [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [7, 9], [8, 10]]

Comment: how do you change the last two to [7,9] and [8,10]?

Comment: @Samantha: You need to add more detail as to what the exact algorithm needs to be then; what happens with different, empty lists?

Comment: Sorry very new.  I'm trying to have every item in the new list to be from a different starting list.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @Samantha: No, not really, actually. :-) Do you have more examples perhaps?

Comment: A_list = [1], B_list = [2, 3], C_list = [4, 5, 6, 7], D_list = [8], answer = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 8], [6], [7]]

Comment: @Samantha: There seems to be no logic in the combinations there. Especially that last `[8]` at the end fails all rules I could think up for this.

Comment: A_list = [1, 2, 3], B_list = [], C_list = [4], D_list = [5, 6], answer = [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]

Comment: sorry I added the 8 on the end by accident.  Does it make more sense?

Comment: And what happens if `C_list` is empty?

Comment: just skip over it. A_list = [1,2,3], B_list = [], C_list = [], D_list = [5,6], answer = [[1,5], [2,6], [3]]

Comment: I have the idea now that `D_list` should only be used to pair with whatever is left of `C_list` after my original algorithm is done. Correct?

Comment: @Samantha: I updated the answer slightly, but it still won't work for the rest of your examples given in the comments here. You need to a) update your *question* (just edit it) to add examples, and b) explain what the full algorithm is supposed to do here. There appears to be little logic in it.

Comment: When I run it on my original lists A_list = [1, 2, 3], B_list = [4], C_list = [5, 6, 7, 8], D_list = [9, 10] the answer turns out being [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [4, 7], [5, 9], [6, 10]]

Comment: @Samantha: Are you saying that your example in the question is incorrect? That answer is simple enough to achieve; just use chain *without* iterator tricks.

Comment: no I'm saying that when I run your above code I get: [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [4, 7], [5, 9], [6, 10]]  and I need answer = [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [7, 9], [8, 10]]

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have a solution for this dubious-sounding problem. Had to resort to `deque`.

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import repeat, izip, izip_longest
A_list = [1, 2, 3]
B_list = [4]
C_list = [5, 6, 7, 8]
D_list = [9, 10]

def popper(x, reserve=None):
  for y in x:
    while y:
      yield y.popleft()
      while reserve:
        yield reserve.popleft()

def generate_couples(A, B, C, D):
  A = deque(izip(A, repeat(1)))
  B = deque(izip(B, repeat(2)))
  C = deque(izip(C, repeat(3)))
  D = deque(izip(D, repeat(4)))
  reserve = deque()
  a, b = popper([A, B, C, D],reserve=reserve), popper([B, C, D]) 
  for (x, y) in izip_longest(a, b):
    if not y:
      yield [x[0], None]
      continue
    while x[1] == y[1]:
      reserve.append(y)
      y = next(b)
    yield [x[0], y[0]]

print list(generate_couples(A_list, B_list, C_list, D_list))
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [7, 9], [8, 10]]
A_list = [1, 2, 3]
B_list = [4]
C_list = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
D_list = [11]
print list(generate_couples(A_list, B_list, C_list, D_list))                
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [7, 11], [8, None], [9, None], [10, None]]
```

Comment: Looks good, except I think OP wants to keep the couples as lists, and doesn't handle the single numbers leftover if there's not another list to pull from as in this ex.  A_list = [1]
B_list = [2,3]
C_list = [4,5,6,7]
D_list = [8]

Comment: Hello Cravoori,  I'm getting a NameError: global name 'next' is not defined.  But I'm unsure what next means here.  Do you have any hints on what I'm doing wrong when running your code?  I'm running it in python 2.5.4

Comment: @Samantha, `next` was introduced with Python 2.6. You may implement [your own next](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652404/import-next-python-2-5) for 2.5

Comment: @ecline6. Thanks. Took care of tuple vs list. As for the single number leftover, will need to give that some thought

Comment: @cravoori  Nice.  I just posted a version that seems to get the job done with a while loop. See what you think.